# Create stored procedure first check and insert XML data in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
create  procedure  [dbo].[usp_xml]
@xml varchar(max),
@jobtransid int
as
if  exists ( SELECT ixbrlxml.xml('@xml')  
FROM   ixbrlxml  
CROSS APPLY [xml].nodes('/iXBRLConf/context') as T2(Loc)  where  jobtransid=@jobtransid)

begin 
print 'error' 
end 
else
begin

UPDATE ixbrlxml
SET [xml].modify('insert @xml (/iXBRLConf/roles)[1]')
where  jobtransid=@jobtransid

end
```

I want to check and insert and update through a stored procedure I have a table that data type is XML

If I execute this I get the error:

> Msg 2209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_xml, Line 16 [Batch Start
>   Line 7] XQuery [ixbrlxml.XML.modify()]: Syntax error near '('

Comment: if I execute this i got the error

Comment: Msg 2209, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_xml, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 7]
XQuery [ixbrlxml.XML.modify()]: Syntax error near '('

Answer (score 0):

There are three flaws:

- You cannot use the variable `@xml` as literal within the `XQuery`. There is `sql:variable()` for your rescue
- You are missing `into`
- You are passing the parameter like `@xml varchar(max)`. This should be `XML`. If there is a good reason to pass a string type, this should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. But - as the target is relying on valid XML - I'd use the appropriate type.

Try this

```
DECLARE @Existing XML='<root><test a="b"/></root>';

DECLARE @xml XML='<NewNode>blah</NewNode>';

SET @Existing.modify('insert sql:variable("@xml") into (/root/test)[1]');

SELECT @Existing;
```

The result

```
<root>
  <test a="b">
    <NewNode>blah</NewNode>
  </test>
</root>
```

### UPDATE

And the fourth problem seems to be this:

```
if  exists ( SELECT ixbrlxml.xml('@xml')  
FROM   ixbrlxml  
CROSS APPLY [xml].nodes('/iXBRLConf/context') as T2(Loc)  where  jobtransid=@jobtransid)
```

What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I want to check the data has existed or not if that exists,  throw the error  not exists insert

Comment: part of XML data

Comment: @ganesh Sorry, this doesn't make any sense for me. Please add a reduced sample of one existing XML and what you try to insert. Add a second case, where you want to reach the `error`. The code above is wrong, but helping you would be wild guessing...

Comment: <element id="fact15">
      <name>dei_EntityExTransitionPeriod</name>
      <value>false</value>
      <context>From2018-01-01TO2018-09-30</context>
      <role>Document - Document and Entity Information</role>
      <rootlevelelement>ucc:DocumentAndEntityInformationAbstract</rootlevelelement>
    </element>
  </hidden>
  <context>

Comment: i want check above data is there or not there in hole Xml file after that if there give 'already exist' otherwise it should be insert under node

Comment: @ganesh, I'm sorry, but I still do not get this... Please use the edit option of your question to provide more (readably formatted) information. At least you must state 1) the existing data, 2) the XML you pass into the SP and 3) the expected output. Show these three things for both cases. Try to reduce your XMLs down to the needed minimum. Best was a *stand-alone* sample like I've provided in my answer.